# how to get list of app installed by ubuntu store

Tags: software-center, kde

I am using Kubuntu 18.4 and I need to get a list of apps installed by ubuntu store (in KDE, discover) so that later I can install them by apt.
how should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting list of installed apps (NOT packages)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151282/getting-list-of-installed-apps-not-packages)

Comment: Does clicking on the "Installed" tab in the Store help?